# Manifolds: show that this map is not a coordinate patch

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $S^1$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by {$(x,y)|x^2+y^2=1$}. We all know that $S^1$ is a 1-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm trying to prove that the following map:$$\alpha:[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^2;\qquad \alpha(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$$

is not a coordinate patch on $S^1$. Does it suffice to show that points near $(0,1)$ need not map under $\alpha^{-1}$ to points near $0$?

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha(t)$ can't be a chart since $[0,1)$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: A coordinate chart is a bijective map from an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to  an open set of your manifold (in this case $n=1$). The set $[0,1)$ is not open, but $(0, 1)$. The latter will not cover the whole manifold though.

Comment: It's open in $\mathbb{H}$

Comment: note that from my book a chart maps either from a set open in $\mathbb{R}^k$ or open in $\mathbb{H}^k$

Comment: Why does it have to be open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because that's the definition of a coordinate chart

Comment: the problem would be too trivial if it was the answer; my book, _Calculus on Manifolds by J. Munkres _ states that a coordinate patch is a continuous map of class $C^r$ that carries a set $U$ that is open in either $\mathbb{R}^k$ or $\mathbb{H}^k$ onto an open set $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a one-to-one fashion such that $D\alpha$ has rank $k$ in $U$ and the inverse is also continuous (given a subset $M$ of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, for each $\mathbf{p} \in M$, $V$ is an open set containing  $\mathbf{p})$

Comment: Usually one only allows open sets in $\Bbb R^n$ when defining a *manifold*, but also allows $\Bbb H^n$ (or equivalent, allows it instead) when defining a *manifold with boundary*.